# Powershell ConvertFrom-Json array string to separate rows

Tags: json, powershell

I have a json file that I'm trying to convert to csv using the converfrom-json command.  I'm having trouble parsing one part of the array string into separate rows.  Here's an example:

```
[
  {
    "GroupName": "A",
    "GroupID": "G001",
    "GroupMemberIds": [
      "M001",
      "M002",
      "M003",
      "M004"
    ]
  },
  {
    "GroupName": "B",
    "GroupID": "G002",
    "GroupMemberIds": [
      "M001",
      "M004",
      "M005",
      "M006"
    ]
  }
]
```

My desired output to csv is:

GroupName   GroupID  GroupMemberId
A       G001    M001
A       G001    M002
A       G001    M003
A       G001    M004
B       G002    M001
B       G002    M004
B       G002    M005
B       G002    M006

I started with the following and tried different iterations but haven't found a solution yet.  any help is greatly appreciated.

```
$obj = Get-Content -Path "C:\Temp\File.json" | ConvertFrom-Json $obj | select groupname, groupid, memberid | export-CSV "C:\Temp\groupmembers.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

here's a sample file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/18WErwuOlU-4068852hsb9S8n9Bs52ndu/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Get-Content -Path "C:\Temp\File.json" | ConvertFrom-Json | ForEach-Object {
    $group = $_;
    $_.GroupMemberIds | ForEach-Object {
        new-object PSCustomObject -Property ([ordered] @{
            "GroupName"     = $group.GroupName
            "GroupId"       = $group.GroupId
            "GroupMemberId" = $_
        })
    }
} | Export-CSV "C:\Temp\groupmembers.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

The first `ForEach-Object` loops over the top-level "group" objects, and the nested `ForEach-Object` loops over each of the entries in its "GroupMemberIds" array and outputs a new object with the GroupName, GroupId, GroupMemberId properties, and *these* are what get converted to a csv file.

```
PS> Get-Content "C:\temp\groupmembers.csv"
"GroupName","GroupId","GroupMemberId"
"A","G001","M001"
"A","G001","M002"
"A","G001","M003"
"A","G001","M004"
"B","G002","M001"
"B","G002","M004"
"B","G002","M005"
"B","G002","M006"
```

**Update** - the above works in PowerShell Core, but not PowerShell 5.1 due to some differences between the way `ConvertTo-Json` outputs array objects - see https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3424 for one example.

A workaround is to put wrap the `ConvertFrom-Json` in a [Grouping Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.1#grouping-operator--) (basically `( ... )`):

```
(Get-Content -Path "C:\Temp\File.json" | ConvertFrom-Json) | ForEach-Object {
    $group = $_;
    $_.GroupMemberIds | ForEach-Object {
        new-object PSCustomObject -Property ([ordered] @{
            "GroupName"     = $group.GroupName
            "GroupId"       = $group.GroupId
            "GroupMemberId" = $_
        })
    }
} | Export-CSV "C:\Temp\groupmembers.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

and then it should work.

Comment: This is an ideal opportunity to use pipelinevariable. Remove $Group = $_  and add -PipelineVariable Group to ConvertFrom-Json

Comment: Thanks, getting close.  For the GroupName and GroupID columns, I'm getting a "System.Object[]" result for each cell.

Comment: @wd510 - that implies your GroupName is more like ```"GroupName": ["A"]``` than  ```"GroupName": "A"``` - check the json for the affected group objects and make sure it matches the format in your sample...

Comment: I doubled-checked it and the format i had in my sample is right, there aren't any brackets around the value for GroupName and GroupID, just quotes.  Only brackets are around the string of values for GroupMemberID.

Comment: @DougMaurer - Nice. every now and then I come across another feature of PowerShell I've been blissfully unaware of, and today's one of those days :-).

Comment: @wd510 - see if you can distill it down to a specific record and then add a simplified version of that to your sample json. you might even find it's a serialization depth issue when the json gets generated and it literally looks like ```"GroupName": "System.Object[]"```!

Comment: @mclayton i stripped it down to just a few records and still getting the same thing.  just to clarify, the json file that's generated literally looks like my sample, there's not system.object[] to be found in the json itself.

Comment: @wd510 - can you add a small example file to the end of your question that can be reproduced with my code? It’s hard to say what the issue is without being able to reproduce it here...

Comment: @mclayton thanks for the suggestion, i added a link to a sample file.

Comment: Ah, this is possibly a difference between ConvertTo-Json in PowerShell 5.1 and PowerShell Core...

Comment: @mclayton this works perfectly.  thanks so much!